# How to change the default to verify="False" for all call to requests across the program

Tags: python, python-requests

In my script office_collector.py I am importing adal and requests. First I make a call to `adal.AuthenticationContext` and then to `adal.acquire_token_with_client_credentials` to get a token. Using this token I make a `requests.get` call to get data from office api's. This works fine under normal conditions but when using a ssl proxy it fails with `SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`.

I can fix this by setting `verify="False"` in the requests.get call in `office_collector.py` but I am assuming that `acquire_token_with_client_credentials` is also making requests get or post calls and those would fail.

I know I can use monkey patching to dynamically change all `requests.get` and `requests.post` calls but don't know how to go about using it as I am a beginner.

Also is there a better way of achieving this by using the session object.

Edit: After trying out the solution by @Jon Clements
relevant parts of the code

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.verify = False
import adal
import json
os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://localhost:8888"
os.environ['https_proxy'] = "http://localhost:8888"
..
..
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(
    authority_url, api_version=None)

token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    resource,
    client_id,
    client_secret)
..
..
token_type = token['tokenType']
access_token = token['accessToken']

header_params = {
'Authorization': token_type + ' ' + access_token
}

request_string = "https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/"+tenant+"/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.Exchange"
```

stack trace:

```
C:\Users\patela28\python_virtualenvs\py2713_09_22\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/patela28/Desktop/test_adal/test_adal.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/patela28/Desktop/test_adal/test_adal.py", line 29, in <module>
    client_secret)
  File "C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\test_adal\lib\adal\authentication_context.py", line 160, in acquire_token_with_client_credentials
    return self._acquire_token(token_func)
  File "C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\test_adal\lib\adal\authentication_context.py", line 109, in _acquire_token
    return token_func(self)
  File "C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\test_adal\lib\adal\authentication_context.py", line 158, in token_func
    return token_request.get_token_with_client_credentials(client_secret)
  File "C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\test_adal\lib\adal\token_request.py", line 316, in get_token_with_client_credentials
    token = self._oauth_get_token(oauth_parameters)
  File "C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\test_adal\lib\adal\token_request.py", line 113, in _oauth_get_token
    return client.get_token(oauth_parameters)
  File "C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\test_adal\lib\adal\oauth2_client.py", line 262, in get_token
    verify=self._call_context.get('verify_ssl', None))
  File "C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\test_adal\lib\requests\api.py", line 107, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\test_adal\lib\requests\api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\test_adal\lib\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\test_adal\lib\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\patela28\Desktop\test_adal\lib\requests\adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `verify` attribute of the session to `False`? (just a straight-forward `s = requests.Session(); s.verify = False`... ?

Comment: In office_collector.py I added the these lines. It fails with the same error as above.

Comment: Where's the exception being raised... is it from the session object or from acquire_token? It'd help if you showed a [mcve]